# java Date and time format

Tags: java, date

how to format "2011-10-25T13:00:00Z" string into date and time

i used simple date format class

```
SimpleDateFormat sim=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

but it only giving the date value. not time values

please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"` for parsing this date format. See the documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info. Code will look like this

```
String dateStr = "2011-09-19T15:57:11Z";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(dateStr);
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because `"yyyy-MM-dd"` only mentions year (`yyyy`), month (`MM`) and date (`dd`). Try adding `hh:mm` if you want hours and minutes.

**Example:**

```
SimpleDateFormat sim = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
System.out.println(sim.format(new Date()));  // prints "2011-10-27 01:56"
```

The full documentation of the format-string and its parts is found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The documentation includes this example:

> `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` - 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700

Perhaps it's something like that you're looking for.

Comment: can u give me pattern string for that

Comment: Added an example from the documentation.

Comment: @surya: Did you try looking at the documentation? Stack Overflow should be the place you ask *after* you've read the documentation and had trouble with it, not a *substitute* for documentation.